# How do I add a "last updated" column (SQL Server)?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database called `a3lf`. On my table `players`, I'd like to add a column called `LastUpdated`. When some part of the row is modified, I'd like that the table `LastUpdated` updates with the time and date info, so I can do some cleaning in a future time.

Is it possible? I was searching for that and I found some code that stills confusing to my knowledge:

```
ALTER TRIGGER dbo.SetLastUpdatedBusiness 
ON dbo.Businesses 
AFTER UPDATE -- not insert!
AS
BEGIN
    IF NOT UPDATE(LastUpdated)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE t
            SET t.LastUpdated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP -- not dbo.LastUpdated!
            FROM dbo.Businesses AS t -- not b!
            INNER JOIN inserted AS i 
            ON t.ID = i.ID;
    END
END
GO
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yes, it is possible - as the code you included already shows. Can you state more clearly what exactly is confusing about that code?

Comment: Just use GetDate() like --> SET t.LastUpdated = GetDate()

Comment: Well, I'm really getting confused about editing the above code to my specific settings, as I'm newbie on this.

Comment: why you need this check `IF NOT UPDATE(LastUpdated)` i think it can be removed. Trigger should work as you expect

Comment: As I said, I'm not sure. I just got that code from other similar question. The "problem" I'm facing is that I'm really newbie to know how to properly replace those examples according to my need. I tried, but no success. So, if someone could help me with this, I'd thank so much! :)

Comment: @user2892436 Why you are saying it is not working. What do you mean by no success

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
This will be the code for your table.

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_players_Update_LastUpdatedColumn
ON <Your_Schema_name>.players
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE <Your_Schema_name>.players
    SET LastUpdated = GETDATE()
    WHERE <ID> IN (SELECT DISTINCT <ID> FROM Inserted).

Generally <ID> is the column, based on which you have updated values (Column used in where filter of an update statement).
```

Hope this helps..!!

Comment: Thank you so much! You just got the point! That's how I'm trying to do:

`CREATE TRIGGER dbo.trg_players_Update_LastUpdatedColumn
ON arma3life.players
AFTER UPDATE
AS
    UPDATE arma3life.players
    SET LastUpdated = GETDATE()
    WHERE 23 IN (SELECT DISTINCT 23 FROM Inserted).`

Unfortunately, I'm receiving this error:

http://i.imgur.com/r2XOCAm.png

Also, is the ID the actual ID or the name of the column?

Thank you so much!

Comment: Hi user2892436,
Its not 23. You should have column name in place of 23.<ID> means the name of the column

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience, Kishore! Do you know something about that error on the image? (http://i.imgur.com/r2XOCAm.png)

Comment: Hey,
Do you have "[SQL] EXPLAIN" in your query at the starting?
If yes, then remove it and run your query. Also, use column name in place of 23. 

Let me know if you are still facing an issue.

Comment: Hi, buddy! Unfortunately, yes, I'm still having a problem! :( This time I'm gonna give you a full picture of my Navicat screen: http://i.imgur.com/xZwH9L9.png | And, no, I'm not using [SQ] EXPLAIN, I think it's just some kind of option that Navicat gives. Thank you again, and have a Happy New Year! :)